# What is v-bind in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am starting with Vue and following the video tutorial by [Traversy Media on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wy9q22isx3U&t=1165s)

There he have used **v-bind** but I  didn't proper explained what are they (or at-least I am unable to get it)

For some reason, I still find documentation slightly hard to comprehend.

So this is what we are doing.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
    <Todos v-bind:todos="todos" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Todos from "./components/todo.vue";
let todo = [
  {
    name: "Rohit",
    title: "Full Stack Developer"
  },
  {
    name: "Varun",
    title: "head of marketing"
  },
];

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Todos
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "hello",
      todos: todo
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**Question:1**  Can someone please comprehend this piece of code

```
 <Todos v-bind:todos="todos" />
```

like what is v-bind and why we are keeping value of todos equal to string? (I understand that ultimately he is passing todos to child component as props)

And then in **todo.vue**, he is doing something like this

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos">
      <h3>{{todo.title}}</h3>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Todos",
  props: ["todos"] 
};
</script>
```

**Question:2** This is where things get pretty scary for me. To start, 
In export default, why would he used an array in props?   `props: ["todos"]`? from the boiler plate code where they pass a string they just did something like this   `props: {msg: String}` so why `props: ["todos"]` here?

```
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    //We are defining the message type here
    msg: String
  }
};
```

**Question 3:**  Lastly in this line right here

```
 <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos">
      <h3>{{todo.title}}</h3>
```

I understand the reason behind doing this `v-bind:key="todo.id"` but then again what is v-bind? where do we use it?

Comment: you could find more details here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks for the comment. I did mention I was unable to comprehend from official docs like what does this mean **keep this element’s title attribute up-to-date with the message property on the Vue instance.** like if someone could explain me in a stretch what v-bind do?

Comment: As a tip you might want to checkout one of these YT channels as well: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSJbGtTlrDami-tDGPUV9-w and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW5YeuERMmlnqo4oq8vwUpg they have some great Vue tutorials

Comment: @SuperDJ I love Both these channels. I learned React from Accadmedia Udemy Course but unfortunately they are very stretchy and I having some time constraints

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Q1**

In Vue you can pass props to child components. If you would have used: `todos="todos"`. `todos` prop would be equal to the string `todos` however with `v-bind:todos` or in short `:todos` it makes the prop the javascript variable `todos`. Which is the `todos` from the `data` function

**Q2**

In vue you can reference the props in different ways. Declaring them in an array is just shorter but has a drawback which is that you can't validate the props. When declaring the props in an object you can specify the type of the prop eg. String, Array, Object etc. It's also possible to declare a default and specifiy required props.

```
props: {
   msg: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
     default: ''
   }
}
```

**Q3**

The example provided won't work as there is no `id` in the `let todo` just `name` and `title`. So what would work is:

```
<div v-bind:key="i" v-for="(todo, i) in todos">
```

Again it's possible to just use `:key="i"`. The key could be seen as an `id`. It's used so Vue knows which element is which in a loop.

Comment: so `v-bind:todos` is `:todos` is `{{todos}}` ? in beginner tutorials is teached often to use `{{todos}}` . bit confusing. feels like there are to many ways doing the same thing.